# RSelenium doesn't find elements on JavaScript produced page

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I need to scrape the 3.5% rate for *Canadian Tire High Interest Savings® Account* on this page:
https://www.ctfs.com/content/ctfs3/en/retailbanking/rates.html

Using a combination of RSelenium and Selector Gadget to get the appropriate CSS I tried:

```
library(RSelenium) # v1.7.9

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$open()


# Requires Java?
# driver <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", chromever = NULL) # can also be "chrome"
# remDr <- driver[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://www.ctfs.com/content/ctfs3/en/retailbanking/rates.html")
  Sys.sleep(2)

  webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", '.css-779o8f:nth-child(1) .css-8vffhu')
```

which resulted in this error:

```
  # Selenium message:Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".css-779o8f:nth-child(1) .css-8vffhu"}
  # For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
  # Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
  # System info: host: '813254d30790', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-156-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
  # Driver info: driver.version: unknown
  # 
  # Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
  # Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
  # class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
  # Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Then I tried to read the source HTML and look for ***3.50*** manually but did not find it.

```
  raw_html <- remDr$getPageSource()
```

Why is this and what is the best way to read the 3.5% interest rate from this page?

Note: I am running Selenium in a Docker container

`docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.1`

or this

`docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:latest`

both produce the same error. @bretauv doesn't seem to have any issues. However, to try it his way requires Java. Ideally, I would like to get RSelenium to work my usual way with the Docker container.

Comment: I edited your post because there was missing code at the beginning. When I run your code, I don't have any error and `webElem$getElementText()` returns a list with `"3.50%*"`. Are you sure the page is fully loaded when you run `findElement()`?